# Parameter is not valid ImageAnimator

Tags: c#, .net, animation

I have this code, which shows the first frame of a gif just fine:

```
img = new Bitmap(fileName);
ulCorner = new Point(100, 100);

using (g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
    {
        g.DrawImage(img, ulCorner); 
    }
ReleaseDC(workerw, dc);
```

but when I use ImageAnimator.Animate to show the entire animation of the gif, I get Parameter is not valid exception:

```
img = new Bitmap(fileName);
ulCorner = new Point(100, 100);

using (g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
    {
        ImageAnimator.Animate(img, (s,e) => { g.DrawImage(img, ulCorner); });
    }
ReleaseDC(workerw, dc);
```

The exception points me to this line:

```
g.DrawImage(img, ulCorner);
```

I also tried the GifImage class from [here](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif2.php), but same results occure.

The gif file is not the problem. 
What should I do?

Comment: Try moving the `using` statement into your lambda expression.  Right now you're capturing a variable that will be disposed.  Also I think you need to call `ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames` to make it go to the next image.  Check out the code sample in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: @juharr Thanks, but an "out of memory" exception was thrown when I moved the `using` statement inside lambda expression. Also, I'm displaying the gif outside the main form, so I can't use the `OnPaint` method to refresh, I tried using a timer, but the "out of memory" exception is preventing me from making more tests.